# JavaFX CSS : Apply hover effect to Child nodes when Parent node is hovered on

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, javafx-css

Is it possible to apply the the hover effects a node's children, when parent node is hovered on, **without** having to hove over each child itself for its hover effect to take place?

For example, suppose i have the following node:

- **HBox** --> **#parent**

  - Label --> **#label**
  - Button --> **#button**

I want to be able to trigger the hover pseudo class of the button and the label, when the Hbox is hovered on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in JavaFX 2 (using the public API) since it does not provide access to pseudoclasses. Even with JavaFX 8+ I would not recommend doing it this way since this would interfere with a pseudoclass that is managed by JavaFX.

You could however apply CSS rules based on the parent's hover state from a CSS stylesheet to make them look the same as a hovered node. The following CSS assumes you add the `hover-container` style class to the parent:

```css
/* a button in a hovered container should look the same as a hovered button */
.hover-container:hover .button {
    -fx-color: -fx-hover-base;
}

/* override above rule for armed buttons */
.hover-container:hover .button:armed {
    -fx-color: -fx-pressed-base;
}
```

Comment: Just one last one last question, is it possible to reference the `pressed border base color` of the parent?